# Sound Recording in AnrdoidJS

Tags: javascript, android, androidjs

I'm trying to get a basic sound recording routine going using [`androidjs`](https://android-js.github.io/). According to [the docs](https://android-js.github.io/docs/microphone_api.html), I should be able to do

```
app.microphone.getDevices(function(devices){
  app.microphone.startRecording({audio:{deviceId:{exact: devices[1]}}});
});
```

in order to start recording, and then

```
app.microphone.stopRecording()
```

in order to stop recording and

```
app.microphone.previewRecording(document.getElementById("preview-audio"), {type: "audio/webm"})
```

preview what I've got so far.

When I build the above and run it on my Android emulator, whet I observe is that the `start` and `stop` routines work (that is, there's a green recording dot in the emulator that appears after I hit "start" and disappears when I hit "stop"), but trying to `preview` does nothing. This is consistent whether I call `preview` before or after `stop`; the target `audio` element stays at 0 runtime regardless of how long I keep recording.

My `index.html` looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <snip .../>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/index.js"></script>
    <snip .../>
  </head>

  <body onload="frontStart()">
    <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="jumbotron my-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <button id="record-button">Record</button>
      <button id="preview-button">Preview</button>
      <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
      <audio id="preview-audio" autoplay controls></audio>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the `frontStart` function referenced in the `body` tag (and defined in `index.js`) looks like

```
function frontStart() {
  $("#record-button").on("click", () => {
    app.microphone.getDevices(function(devices){
      app.microphone.startRecording({audio:{deviceId:{exact: devices[1]}}});
    });
  });
  $("#preview-button").on("click", () => {
    app.microphone.previewRecording(document.getElementById("preview-audio"), {type: "audio/webm"})
  });
  $("#stop-button").on("click", () => {
    app.microphone.stopRecording()
  });
}
```

As I mention above; clicking the `start` and `stop` buttons seems to work as expected, but clicking `preview` does nothing regardless of whether it happens before or after `stop` *or* `start`.

What am I doing wrong here?